# How to merge two images but ignore same elements?

Tags: java, image, merge, photo, bufferedimage

I want to make a screenshot and then scroll and make screenshot again, then merge these two images in one, but ignore the same elements.

I know how to merge two images in java but don't know how to ignore the equal parts.

```
public static BufferedImage joinBufferedImage(BufferedImage img1,BufferedImage img2) {

    //do some calculate first
    int offset  = 5;
    int wid = img1.getWidth()+img2.getWidth()+offset;
    int height = Math.max(img1.getHeight(),img2.getHeight())+offset;
    //create a new buffer and draw two image into the new image
    BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(wid,height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = newImage.createGraphics();
    Color oldColor = g2.getColor();
    //fill background
    g2.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, wid, height);
    //draw image
    g2.setColor(oldColor);
    g2.drawImage(img1, null, 0, 0);
    g2.drawImage(img2, null, img1.getWidth()+offset, 0);
    g2.dispose();
    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is called stitching.

I would recommend to use some library that supports stitching such as OpenCV.
There is a Java port of OpenCV and if you search for something like "OpenCV stitcher" you will find plenty of tutorials